# Why does IntelliJ IDEA not separate the WEB/EJB/JPA/... projects?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, intellij-idea

When using NetBeans, if I make a WEB+JPA+EJB project, I will be able to see 3 projects in the projects list. This way, I can manage which files each project can see.

However in IntelliJ, it shows up as one project.

I have noticed there are the tool panels on the side for Web, JPA and etc. However, when making the persistence, it was only made for the JPA. It was not included in the EJB.jar or the EAR file. I had to copy the persistence.xml into META-INF folders of the /web folder and etc. in order to fix this.

This doesn't seem really clear, which folder belongs to which (ejb/etc). Is it possible to separate this in IntelliJ IDEA, like in NetBeans?

If not, would it be possible to make it clear how it works? I think I'm missing something about this.

Comment: You can create separate modules of different types within an IntelliJ project. Take a look at the online documentation for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ supports only one project per window, but what you are looking for is called multi modules project. Create a project and then create a JPA module, a EJB module and a WEB module, just right click the project root folder and choose New -> Module. Read about it in the IDE help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I needed :). If I checked these modules when making the new project, they don't show up as separate folders, but this way they do!